# How to traversal through IBM Graph using bluemix

Tags: ibm-graph

I am trying write a gremlin query on how to display IBM graph with n number of child edges and vertex . if user has provided some index word , for example "acquisition" is index search word, the following query return a good result

```
 def g = graph.traversal();g.V().has('entityString', 'acquisition').bothE().otherV().path()
```

But I would like to traversal through all its linked nodes and then its child nodes and its edges. 
The output result of the above query is following:

```
[
  {
    "labels": [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ],
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": 40964248,
        "label": "EventBusiness",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "ody4z-oe07s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "odyj7-oe07s-sl",
              "value": "acquisition"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "oe1ar-oe07s-153p-6cw",
        "label": "affectedBy",
        "type": "edge",
        "inVLabel": "Organization",
        "outVLabel": "EventBusiness",
        "inV": 8240,
        "outV": 40964248
      },
      {
        "id": 8240,
        "label": "Organization",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "2rq-6cw-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "35y-6cw-sl",
              "value": "agencies"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "labels": [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ],
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": 40964248,
        "label": "EventBusiness",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "ody4z-oe07s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "odyj7-oe07s-sl",
              "value": "acquisition"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "odyxf-oe07s-17h1-37s",
        "label": "agentOf",
        "type": "edge",
        "inVLabel": "Organization",
        "outVLabel": "EventBusiness",
        "inV": 4168,
        "outV": 40964248
      },
      {
        "id": 4168,
        "label": "Organization",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "16x-37s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "1l5-37s-sl",
              "value": "DoD"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "labels": [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ],
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": 40964248,
        "label": "EventBusiness",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "ody4z-oe07s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "odyj7-oe07s-sl",
              "value": "acquisition"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "odzbn-oe07s-17h1-37s",
        "label": "agentOf",
        "type": "edge",
        "inVLabel": "Organization",
        "outVLabel": "EventBusiness",
        "inV": 4168,
        "outV": 40964248
      },
      {
        "id": 4168,
        "label": "Organization",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "16x-37s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "1l5-37s-sl",
              "value": "DoD"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "labels": [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ],
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": 40964248,
        "label": "EventBusiness",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "ody4z-oe07s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "odyj7-oe07s-sl",
              "value": "acquisition"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2dv-oe07s-17h1-3bs",
        "label": "agentOf",
        "type": "edge",
        "inVLabel": "Organization",
        "outVLabel": "EventBusiness",
        "inV": 4312,
        "outV": 40964248
      },
      {
        "id": 4312,
        "label": "Organization",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "17f-3bs-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "1ln-3bs-sl",
              "value": "AT&L"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "labels": [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ],
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": 40964248,
        "label": "EventBusiness",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "ody4z-oe07s-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "odyj7-oe07s-sl",
              "value": "acquisition"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "1cruab-oe07s-17h1-6i0",
        "label": "agentOf",
        "type": "edge",
        "inVLabel": "Organization",
        "outVLabel": "EventBusiness",
        "inV": 8424,
        "outV": 40964248
      },
      {
        "id": 8424,
        "label": "Organization",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "verified": [
            {
              "id": "2sd-6i0-4eth",
              "value": true
            }
          ],
          "entityString": [
            {
              "id": "36l-6i0-sl",
              "value": "DoD Component TSN"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you provide a small example graph and expected output from the traversal? It sounds to me you just want to add another `.bothE().otherV()` to `g.V().has('entityString', 'acquisition').bothE().otherV()`

Comment: It would also be useful if you could provide examples of what you've already tried to get the result you want.

Comment: @pantalohnes  the query you provided works great. It does show the  second degree node. How would I do it for 12 children nodes. I assume something do with repeat and limit query.

Comment: You could do something along the lines of `g.V().has('entityString', 'acquisition').repeat(bothE().otherV()).times(12).path()`. Another option would be to repeat until some criteria is met, e.g. `g.V().has('entityString', 'acquisition').repeat(bothE().otherV()).until(someConditionIsMet).path()`. The second traversal may be worth adding a `limit` to.